# stop cursor until text is changed in textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, textarea

Trying to allow a user to type into a textarea, but if a certain word is seen, I would like the cursor to stop until that word is removed.

I have finding the word, but I am unable find a way to have the cursor stop.

Any ideas on how i would do this in javascript

```
 $(function() {
            $('#ideacomment').bind('keyup', function(e){
                var characterLimit = 300;
                charactersUsed = $(this).val().length;

                if(charactersUsed > characterLimit){
                    charactersUsed = characterLimit;
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
                    $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
                }
                var charactersRemaining = characterLimit - charactersUsed;
                $('#remainingCharacters').html(charactersRemaining);

                 var words = $('#ideacomment').val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
                 var wordcount = words.length;
                 var nonewords = new Array("f**k", "you");
                 var nonewordcount = nonewords.length;
                //console.log(nonewordcount + ' is the count');

                for(var i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) {

                    for(var t = 0; t < nonewordcount; t++) {
                        if(words[i] == nonewords[t]) {
                            message('No swearing please! <br><br> This post will not succeed!<br><br> Please remove it before you continue!', '430');
                            }
                        }
            }
            });


      });
```

The code above counts the number of chars and also checks each word.  Would I would like and I have tried without success is have it as if it ran out of space.  But i have been unable to make it happen using the same code the limiter?

This is the new code.  Still not working though:

```
        $(function() {
            $('#ideacomment').bind('keyup', function(e){
                var characterLimit = 300;
                charactersUsed = $(this).val().length;

                if(charactersUsed > characterLimit){
                    charactersUsed = characterLimit;
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, characterLimit));
                    $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
                }
                var charactersRemaining = characterLimit - charactersUsed;
                $('#remainingCharacters').html(charactersRemaining);

                 var nonewords = new Array("hey", "you");
                 var nonewordcount = nonewords.length;
                 for(var t = 0; t < nonewordcount; t++) {
                     if ($(this).val().indexOf(nonewords[t]) != -1) {
                        message('No swearing please! <br><br> This post will not succeed!<br><br> Please remove it before you continue!', '430');
                         var keycode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                            console.log(keycode);
                            if (keycode !== 8 && keycode !== 46)
                                return false;
                                }   
    }

                 });
            });
```

Comment: It would help if you posted code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Define the "stopping of the cursor" part please

Comment: I need no more text to be typed until the word is removed

Comment: How would the user be able to remove the word if it's readonly or disabled ?

Comment: So you're telling me you don't want people to talk about assassins or mishits? You're taking the wrong approach to this issue.

Comment: Thanks zzzzBov, your about right.  Swear words but also words like "you", "your" etc needs to be stopped.   If this is the wrong way of doing it, whats the correct way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check which key is being pressed, and block it if it is not a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Here is a simplified example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#textbox').keydown(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('test') != -1) {
            var keycode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
            if (keycode !== 8 && keycode !== 46)
                return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CpTFd/)**

Since you already seem to have the text-checking and notification part, all you're really missing is just the keypress-blocking part.

Comment: Thats good Zhihao and it works in the text box, but i am unable to make it work on a textarea?

Comment: `var words = $('#ideacomment').val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
var wordcount = words.length;
var nonewords = new Array("f**k", "you", "test");
var nonewordcount = nonewords.length;
for(var i = 0; i < wordcount; i++) {
for(var t = 0; t < nonewordcount; t++) {
if(words[i] == nonewords[t]) {
 message('No swearing please! <br><br> This post will not succeed!<br><br> Please remove it before you continue!', '430');
if ($(this).val().indexOf('test') != -1) {
var keycode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
if (keycode !== 8 && keycode !== 46) {
return false;
}
}
}
}
}`

Comment: It seems to work for me using `textarea` and your code (minus the word-grabbing part). **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CpTFd/1/)**

Comment: It does work on the example, but I get an ILLEGAL TOKEN if I replace my code with yours.

Comment: @AndrewWalker I don't have your page or your exact requirements, so it would be difficult for me to write the exact code for you. You will probably have to adapt the code I've provided to work for you. That being said, I would need more details to help you debug your issue. If you get any errors, you should be able to see what it is and where it's coming from through your browser's developer tools.

Comment: +1 Looked over the code with fresh eyes and found the problem with the `function() {` part of the code.  Not sure why.  But thank you for your time in helping me with this.